# Ошибка Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in Z:

Tags: php

```
Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$file = "test2.txt";
$a=fopen($file,w) or die("File ($file) does not exist!"); // значение
$b=$a+1;$a=$b.".txt";
$file2=$a;
$filetext=" Привет " ;
echo $file2; echo $b;
$f=fopen($file2,w) or die("File ($file2) does not exist!"); // Сздать файл
if (fwrite($file2,$filetext) === FALSE) {
    echo "Не могу произвести запись в файл ($file2)";
    exit;
}

echo "Ура! Записали ($somecontent) в файл ($file2)";

fwrite($file, $b);
fclose($f) or die("File ($file) does not exist!"); 
fclose($a) or die("File ($file) does not exist!");
```

В браузере выдаёт следущёё:

```
4.txt 4
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in Z:\home\RBK\WWW\test2.php on line 26
Не могу произвести запись в файл (4.txt)
```

В файле `test2.txt` занесенна цифра 1 .....  при чёт тут 4 я не пойму. Файл `4.txt` создаётся но почемуто не доступен к записи

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Мои глаза округлились настолько, что после этого не могу читать дальше:  

    $a=fopen($file,w);
    $b=$a+1;
[PHP:fopen](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php)

Comment: // складываем тип resource с числом О_О, после приведения типов результат вроде должен быть числом 
$b=$a+1; 

Число будет увеличиваться на 1  с каждым обращением к скрипту результат сохраняется в Test2.txt Да кстати с этим проблемма при чтении из этого файза переиенной $a не присваивается значение 1

Comment: // неожиданно опечатываемся и пишем $file2 вместо $f 
if (fwrite($file2,$filetext) === FALSE) { 
    echo "Не могу произвести запись в файл ($file2)"; 
    exit; 
} 

ВОТ ОНО !!!!! Опромное человеческое спасибо ))))

// а здесь нет, $a это уже строка 
fclose($a) or die("File ($file) does not exist!"); 

исправил скрипт работает 


Осталась проблемма со счётсиком обращения к скрипту (((

Comment: @сергейсергей, подумайте ещё раз, получше. `$a` - это не число, это идентификатор открытого вами файла. Вы вообще никак не должны его использовать, кроме как в качестве аргумента для функций fwrite, fread, fclose и т.д.

Comment: Понятно ..... Но как тогда присвоить переменной значение сохранённое в текстовом файле ???

Comment: чтение строки из файла:

    $file_to_read = fopen($file_name, 'r'); 
    fgets($file_to_read, $some_string);

А вообще ссылку на документацию уже дали, неужели так сложно почитать?

Answer (score 3):

Половина ваших проблем связана с нежеланием читать документацию, другая половина - с неумением выстроить логическую цепочку:

- [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fwrite.php) ругается на то, что он ожидает ссылку на файл (созданную через [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php)), а вы передаете ему имя файла
- только вот ссылку на файл (ваш `$a`) вы уже убили через присваивание, сделав `$a=$b.".txt"`
- к тому же, файл вы открыли только для записи, но при этом хотите что-то прочитать из него
- и читаете почему-то через [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php), хотя он просто возвращает ссылку на файл
- а само "чтение из файла" (например, [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgets.php)) вы так и не добавили
- и кто вас научил использовать такие имена? Почему нельзя переменные называть так, чтобы было понятно что они делают?
- и текст всегда должен быть текстом (я про `w` в `fopen($file,w)`). Да, необъявленные константы вида `w` преобразуются в строку по имени константы, но ошибкой это быть не перестает

Ваш код будет намного короче (а значит и ошибок там будет меньше), если делать через обертки:

```
$inputFileName = 'test2.txt';
$storedValue = file_get_contents($inputFileName);

$newValue = intval($storedValue) + 1;
$outputFileName = "$newValue.txt";

file_put_contents($outputFileName, 'your text');
file_put_contents($inputFileName, $newValue);
```

Тоже не идеально, т.к. не проверяю возможные ошибки, но это же просто пример

Если же вам надо разобраться с работой с файлами, то тогда бы я посоветовал вынести каждую операцию в отдельную функцию. Т.е. создал бы те же обертки, которые можно было бы легко отлаживать (т.к. можно было бы проверять работу каждой функции отдельно):

```
function read_from_file($fileName) {
    $fileHandler = fopen($fileName, 'r');
    if (false === $fileHandler) {
        return false;
    }

    $line = fgets($fileHandler);
    fclose($fileHandler);
    return $line;
}

function write_to_file($fileName, $text) {
    $fileHandler = fopen($fileName, 'w');
    if (false === $fileHandler) {
        return false;
    }

    $byteWrites = fwrite($fileHandler, $text);
    fclose($fileHandler);
    return $byteWrites;
}

$inputFileName = 'test2.txt';
$storedValue = read_from_file($inputFileName);
$newValue = intval($storedValue) + 1;
$outputFileName = "$newValue.txt";

write_to_file($outputFileName, 'your text');
write_to_file($inputFileName, $newValue);
```

(опять почти не смотрю на ошибки)